# Is there a way to disable the print dialog box in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, printing

Does anyone know how to disable the print dialog box so that when I select print, the page will print without any popup boxes or windows? I want do this configuration XP.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on application, could you not use "Quick Print?". For example, IE and Office have the option to "bypass" the print dialogue and just print using the default settings.
[image]